# Calling Api with multiple parameter under Conditional statement

Tags: android

I am passing **3** parameter and feeding it to the api

Paramters are: ***userName, creditpoints, action(+/-).***

So I have some rules to send value according to the user rating which is from 0.0 - 5.0

Rule Set(creditpoints,action) :

> 1.0--> 2,-
>
> 2.0--> 1,-
>
> 3.0--> 1,+
>
> 4.0--> 2,+
>
> 5.0--> 3,+

I could do this with **if and else if** but in each condition I have to put the **same** code again and again.

What could be the **best possible case** to do this and in a few lines with minimum **complexity**.

Comment: Impossible to tell. Show code.

Comment: If it's the same code and only the value changes, why not simply put the value and dismiss the condition?

Comment: @TimCastelijns If I had implemented in the best possible case why would I ask it here in the first place

Comment: ... show the existing code, where you have to add this functionality

Comment: @MuratK. I know murat that simple if and else would do the work and only true condtion will be executed to call api but I guess this seems to be wrong!

Comment: @TimCastelijns look code added

Comment: what's wrong with this code?

Comment: See where I have added "here....to send update credit" there I have add if and else if for all the condtion .......I guess this is not the best practice to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this with minimal code, would be to find some algorithmic pattern in the arguments.

In your case, e.g. action is "-" for rating < 3 and "+" for rating >= 3, so you could handle the action parameter like so:

```
apiCall(userName, creditPoints, rating < 3 ? "-" : "+");
```

Similar, creditPoints have a pattern: for rating < 3 the value is 3 - rating, for rating >= 3 its rating - 2. So the final api call would be:

```
apiCall(
    userName, 
    rating < 3 ? 3 - rating : rating - 2,
    rating < 3 ? "-" : "+"
);
```